# C: using "scanf" to read a float within a line of other characters

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I am new to C and am writing a program that acts as a calculator, where each line of input code begins with an operator and then contains potential whitespace, a number, more potential whitespace, and a line break. I am instructed to use `getchar` to read everything except the float, and `scanf` to read the float.

I am unsure how to use `scanf` to read a float that is mixed within a line of other characters.  The below code shows most of the while loop which also includes the reading of the rest of the characters, but the most relevant part is the last 3 lines.

```
while (1) { 
    int ic = getchar(); 
    if (ic < 0) 
        break;   //EOF 
    char temp = (char) ic;
    if (temp == '+' || temp == '-' || temp == '*' || temp == '/' || 
        temp == '=' || temp == 'C' || temp == 'Q'){ 
        op = (char) ic;
    }
    if (temp >= '0' && temp <= '9'){
        char valu = scanf("%c", &temp);
        val = (double) valu; 
...
```

I expected the value to be read that is in the input line, yet when I print it, it is always displayed as `"1.0000"`.

Answer (score 2):

**Step by step**

I recommend to not skimp of good error checking.  Assume user input can be unexpected.

> where each line of input code begins with an operator

Much like OP's code

```
int ic = getchar(); 
if (ic == '+' || ic == '-' || ic == '*' || ic == '/' || ic == '=' || ic == 'C' ||ic == 'Q'){ 
   op = (char) ic;
} else (ic == EOF) {
  break; //EOF 
} else {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input %d\n", ic);
  break;
}
```

> and then contains potential whitespace,

Use `isspace()` to test for white-space.

```
while (isspace( (ic = getchar()) )) {
  ;
}
unget(ic, stdin);  // ic is not a white-space - put it baack
```

> a number,

Be sure to check the `scanf()` return value.  A key attribute about `"%f"` is that it consumes leading white-spaces, including `'\n'`.  To detect a `'\n'` before the number, the prior `isspace()` loop was useful.  Now code knows the first character it is to read is *not* any white-space.

```
float f;
int cnt = scanf("%f", &f);
if (cnt != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected FP input\n");
  break;
}
```

> more potential whitespace and a line break.

Remember that `'\n'` is a white-space too.

```
while ((ic = getchar()) != '\n' && isspace(ic)) {
  ;
}
if (ic != '\n') {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected trailing text %d\n", ic);
  break;
}

// Success
```

---

When code does not reach success, code should consume all input up to a `'\n'` or `EOF` before attempting to parse a new line of text.